# Exclude a deep subdirectory from an .htaccess RedirectMatch

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The site's .htaccess file has this existing command:

```
RedirectMatch 404 /directory(/|$)
```

An exception is required to make files from one deep subdirectory accessible while still returning a 404 for all other files under directory. The path to the accessible directory is:

```
/directory/sub/sub/sub/sub
```

If I comment out the existing RedirectMatch, the files in the subdirectory are accessible, but so are all the other contents of /directory. I've tried retaining the RedirectMatch and putting a RewriteRule at the top of the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^/directory/sub/sub/sub/sub/ - [L]
```

I've tried replacing the the RedirectMatch with a RewriteCond and RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/directory/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory/sub/sub/sub/sub/.*$
RewriteRule ^/directory/(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
```

So far nothing has been effective. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to exclude the subdirectory, like so:

```
 RedirectMatch 404 /directory(?!/sub/sub/sub/sub)
```

You'll also notice that I've removed the check for the trailing slash *or* end of string. Reason being: directories always have trailing slash (unless `DirectorySlash` is set to `off`). Also, no need to check for the end of the path because you're matching everything in `directory` and the subdirectory (for exclusion).

Comment: Thanks Mike! This is an excellent answer and does exactly what I need. I'd upvote it but this account doesn't have the requisite 15 points.